# how can i hold button and text in the bottom of box in css

Tags: html, css

I have a one text, and one button.
I want to move two of them (button and text) to bottom of the note box.

now its like this:
[image: its like this]

i want to like this:
[image: i want to like this]

can you help me please?

my codes:

html codes of my project:

```
return (
    <div className="note">
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>

      <hr className="solid"></hr>
      <p>{props.content}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClickAndDelete}>
        <TrashIcon />
      </button>
      <div className="noteTimezone">
      <p>{props.timezone}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

css codes of my project:

```
.note {
  width: 320px;
  height: 370px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 30px auto 20px auto;
  float: left;
}

.note h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.note p {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.note button {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px, 0px, 15px, 25px;
  color: #ff5733;
  border: none;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.noteTimezone {
  color: rgb(138, 137, 137);
}
```

Comment: Please use https://codesandbox.io or a playground of your choice to show your output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this code:
```

```css
.note {
  width: 320px;
  height: 370px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 30px auto 20px auto;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.note h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.note p {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.note button {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px, 0px, 15px, 25px;
  color: #ff5733;
  border: none;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.noteTimezone {
  color: rgb(138, 137, 137);
}

.footer{
  color: rgb(138, 137, 137);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width:90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="note">
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>

      <hr class="solid"></hr>
      <p>{props.content}</p>
      <div  class="footer">
        <button>
            TrashIcon
        </button>
        <div class="noteTimezone">
            <p>{props.timezone}</p>
        </div>
      <div>
 </div>
```

can also read this article for more info on positioning : https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: it worked for button. I suppose i can do the same thing for text. Thanks dude <3